# how to separate a column of one ASCII file and add it to the last column of another ASCII file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to separate the last column of one ASCII file and add it to the end of another ASCII. So far I did the following codes and I was expecting it would work. I would be thankful if sb assist me to find out what is mistake.

```
import os,sys,csv

filename = 'E:\AirborneLidarData\IntensFirst\325115401.asc'
outfilename = 'E:\AirborneLidarData\LaserFirst\325115401.asc'

csv_out = csv.writer(open(outfilename, 'w'), delimiter=' ')

f = open(filename,'r')
for line in f:
   vals = line.split('\t')
   for item in csv_out:
      csv_out.writerow(item.strip() , vals[3])
```

here is an example of just 5 rows of both datasets.

infile:

```
32511999.00 5401190.00   18.00
32511999.50 5401190.00   18.00
32511998.50 5401190.50   15.00
32511999.00 5401190.50   16.50
32511999.50 5401190.50   17.62
```

outfile:

```
32511999.00 5401190.00  313.98  
32511999.50 5401190.00  313.98  
32511998.50 5401190.50  314.10  
32511999.00 5401190.50  314.04  
32511999.50 5401190.50  313.99
```

Comment: You cannot treat a `writer()` as a reader at the same time. You'll have to replace the input file by using a temporary intermediary. Why not use the input file as a `csv` file too, since it uses tab delimiters?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. well, I tried to edit the code and used    f = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'), delimiter=' ') this time for reading. The problem I have faced is that, it can not read the file and gives the error  :  [errno 2]no such file or directory:....\xd5115401.asc     though the file is there and it shows that the name of the reading file is different

Comment: That's because `\325` is interpreted as a special character. Use double slashes or `r''` raw strings or forward slashes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to loop over both *input files* first, combining the rows, writing out to a temporary file. Then move the temporary file back to your intended output file. You don't actually have CSV data, but rather data that uses an arbitrary number of spaces as delimiters. You need to handle that manually, but we'll write out using the csv module:

```
import csv
import tempfile
import shutil
from itertools import izip

with open(filename, 'rb') as infile1, open(outfilename, 'r+b') as infile2:
    outfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')

    for line1, line2 in izip(infile1, infile2):
        row1, row2 = line1.split(), line2.split()
        outcsv.writerow(row2 + [row1[2]])

    # rewind files to start; alternative is to close both and use `shutil.copyfile()`
    outfile.seek(0)
    infile2.seek(0)
    shutil.copyfileobj(outfile, infile2)
    outfile.close()
```

The above code opens `outfilename` for both reading and writing (mode `r+b`) to easy the copying back of the temporary file contents. I'm assuming that the `filename` and `outfilename` have the same number of rows; if they don't, any extra rows in either file will be ignored. You can use `itertools.izip_longest()`, but you'll have to come up with a strategy deciding what to fill in for the missing rows in that case.

You also need to avoid using `\123` escape sequences in your filenames. Use forward slashes, raw strings or double the backslashes:

```
filename = 'E:\\AirborneLidarData\\IntensFirst\\325115401.asc'
outfilename = 'E:\\AirborneLidarData\\LaserFirst\\325115401.asc'
```

or

```
filename = r'E:\AirborneLidarData\IntensFirst\325115401.asc'
outfilename = r'E:\AirborneLidarData\LaserFirst\325115401.asc'
```

or

```
filename = 'E:/AirborneLidarData/IntensFirst/325115401.asc'
outfilename = 'E:/AirborneLidarData/LaserFirst/325115401.asc'
```

will all work as they avoid the backslashes being interpreted as escape sequences.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind assistant. You are right ,it works when I change the reading format.   About the above code, does it need any closing?!

Comment: @user2355306: No, the `with` statement will close the files for us. Except for the `tempfile.NamedTempfile`, it can do with an explicit close in this case (in Python 3 we can also use it as a context manager, so with the `with` statement).

Comment: ok, I see, that was a new information for me. Thank you. Well, I tried the code but it stucks at the line 'outcsv.writerow(row2 + [row1[3]])' and gives the error : list index out of range. What you think is the problem?

Comment: @user2355306: `row1` does not *have* four values in that case. Are there empty lines in the file, or lines with fewer than 4 values?

Comment: To be honest I have got confused. The code is running now and there is no error. But when I open the outfile, nothing has changed and it is the same as before.

Comment: @user2355306: That doesn't sound right either. If the code completes without error, **and** there is still data in the outputfile afterwards, we managed to write something to the file.

Comment: Dear Martijn Pieters, you are right that when there is no error it means that we have managed it, but the output file just has its own three columns and no new column has been added. As I said earlier, there is a error on' 'outcsv.writerow(row2 + [row1[2]])'line( I changed the column number). I edit the line  incsv1 = csv.reader(infile1, delimiter='\t') to  incsv1 = csv.reader(infile1, delimiter=' ') and that is the reason that it works without error but I think it has influenced the result file. If that is so, I have to solve the error then. We have two file in each 3 columns.

Comment: Right, when there is an error then your files are not altered; that is a good thing. :-) You may need to share some lines from both files to show me what you are working with here. It could be you have empty lines or data that doesn't easily work with `csv`.

Comment: so, may I ask what is your opinion about the data?

Comment: @user2355306: So, you have 3 columns, not 4, and both have tab delimited data, I think. I've adjusted my answer to assume all files use tab delimiting, and that you want the 3rd, not 4th column (`row1[2]`, python uses 0-based indexing).

Comment: Thank you for your edition. Well, right now we can have the output file but it is totally empty :(

Comment: @user2355306: I am not certain that you have tab delimited data, though; I cannot be certain that you copied your rows over without replacing tab characters with spaces. What you have in your question is *space delimited*, and that won't work correctly with the `csv` module.

Comment: Dear Martijn Pieters, could we change the code in a way that , we have an output which has the fist three column of the infile2 and the last column of the infile1? since in this way my original data would not be affected. could we do without csv?!

Comment: @user2355306: already updated to not use `csv` for the input files, but still using `csv` for the outputfile as that is still easier.